# rendering multiple elements based on condition

Tags: reactjs

i have an array of objects where based on some property condition I am showing some elements. So I have seen both ways are there. But which is the right one and any performance advantage there. As of now I have shown only one property, but there can be more than three or four properties. So which is right and better. I see the second way as more cleaner, but there is a variable added then if its false then it will be null so which is right and better

Way1

```
return (
  <Fragment>
    <div>Data displayed</div>
    <div className='container'>
      <div>List of details</div>
      {datumn?.is_allowed && <span>Show Details</span>}
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

Way2

```
let showDetails = null;

if(datumn?.is_allowed){
  showDetails  = (
    <span>Show Details</span>
  )
}

return (
  <Fragment>
    <div>Data displayed</div>
    <div className='container'>
      <div>List of details</div>
      {showDetails}
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

Comment: I prefer the first way since you are saving the variable declaration and you keep all of the html in the return statement, i think it's more readable this way. But both are valid it's really a preference. React also suggests both can be used in the docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: But assume if have datumn?.is_allowed, datumn?.is_completed, datumn?.is_mentioned something like these then if I use the second approach then is there any performance of memory kind of issues ?@DannyMoshe

Comment: I don't think there is a clear better way, this is more about readability in my opinion. Which one do you find more readable and understandable? I prefer Way1 in my own code as Danny mentioned to keep things together.

Comment: Sure as more people suggest way1 will follow the same, since I am also learning on react thanks @Sead

Comment: There is no performance issue in fact way 1 will be more performant in terms of memory. In the case that the logic grows to be complex you could create a variable to encapsulate the condition and use that in the return statement.

Comment: Okay so if more complex conditions are there then use way2 isn't @DannyMoshe

Comment: @dev Not necessarily way2 but just create single bool to encapsulate the condition
`const showDetails = datumn?.is_allowed && datumn?.is_completed && datumn?.is_mentioned` and use that as you have used is_allowed on it's own, that's like middle ground

Comment: No each property has different elements to show, each has different set of actions so